# How to correctly use nanosleep() to run code at specific frequency?

Tags: c, delay

I am making an emulator for the 6502 CPU and i want to control the frequency at which it is running.

Without any delay, my max average frequency is about 70-80 MHz. However, when i try to use nanosleep in order to control frequency, it only works until i reach 1 mS delay (1000000 nS).
If i try to set the delay any lower, for example to .1 mS, it does not change the average execution timing. What is strange to me is that if i set the delay to .1 mS, the actual delay turns out to be ~.008 mS and it does not change for any value in range 1-99999 nS.

I have tried compiling the code both in debug and release mode

Am i using nanosleep wrong? It is my first time using nanosleep, i have only used sleep and usleep before, so i am a bit confused.
Is there any better way to control the frequency of code execution?

Comment: Please post the code containing the function calls and variable declarations.

Comment: use a timer instead. Sleeping isn't the way to run code periodically

Comment: If you need very fine control over timing, you need to check the actual time elapsed since your last tick, instead of just assuming (nano)sleep was perfectly accurate. Once your process could be de-scheduled for longer than your tick duration (unless you also use the realtime scheduler class as in Kamil's answer), you also need to handle catching up missed ticks.

Comment: I suppose it would be smarter to calculate 1024 steps or something like that at once and then sleep, otherwise the overhead from sleeping is far more expensive than your actual work.

Comment: You should count (virtual) CPU cycles, and have a variable delay (possibly a loop or other mechanism), which brings the cycles in line with the time elapsed, to get an exact frequency. Have a timer that checks the number of virtual CPU cycles periodically, if the CPU is running too fast then increase the delay, too slow, then decrease the delay. Alternatively, count an exact number of cycles and see how much real time has elapsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to correctly use nanosleep() to run code at specific frequency?

I say it's impossible to use `nanosleep` to run code at specific frequency (or, it's possible, up to a certain accuracy with some drift?). From [`man nanosleep`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nanosleep.3p.html) emphasis mine, but whole is relevant:

> The nanosleep() function shall cause the current thread to be suspended from execution until either the time  interval  specified
> by  the  rqtp  argument has elapsed or a signal is delivered to the calling thread, and its action is to invoke a signal-catching
> function or to terminate the process. **The suspension time may be longer than requested** because the argument value is  rounded  up
> to  an integer multiple of the sleep resolution or because of the scheduling of other activity by the system. But, except for the
> case of being interrupted by a signal, the suspension time shall **not be less** than the time specified by rqtp, as measured by  the
> system clock CLOCK_REALTIME.

> Is there any better way to control the frequency of code execution?

Use timers and try to depend on the kernel to properly schedule periodic execution, rather then doing it yourself. Use `timer_create` to request an interrupt after specified timeout and run your code after that timeout, and you may also consider making your process a real-time process. In pseudocode I think I would:

```
void timer_thread(union sigval s) {
    do_your_code();
}
int main() {
   timer_t t;
   timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &(struct sigevent){
        .sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD,
        .sigev_notify_function = timer_thread
   }, &t);
   timer_settime(t, &(struct itimerspec){{.tv_sec = 1},{.tv_sec = 1}}, 0);
   while (1) {
      // just do nothing - code will be triggered in separate thread by timer
      pause();
   }
}
```