# Linux Realtime clock_nanosleep function

Tags: linux, real-time

I had install the RT-Patches on my Linux system and it seems to work. Execution of cyclictest delivers values under 60us. But if I use the clock_nanospeed function in my code the derivation between delay_time (times_meas[2]) and realtime is up to 400us. I couldn't find the root cause for it:-(
I also modified the thread code that the memory for all local variables are occupied with alloc.

```
if (clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, TIMER_ABSTIME, &times_meas[2], NULL) != 0)
{
      ;
}
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &times_meas[0] );
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: No, `clock_nanosleep` doesn't sleep for specified amount of time, it sleeps for __at least__ the specified amount of time. Please re-read linux-man page.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But in my opinion cyclictest is working so.It sleeps for a while and then gets the time and compares with the sleep time. I want to realize a "trigger" every 20ms with a jitter under 100us, how can I realize that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to correctly use nanosleep() to run code at specific frequency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63773919/how-to-correctly-use-nanosleep-to-run-code-at-specific-frequency) Lol, the title of the question is misleading